# How to generate a dataframe with the same structure for multiple periods

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe for one period and want to generate a dataframe for each period with the same structure. Here is the code that works. Is there a more elegant way to do this in tidyverse?

```
library(tidyverse) 
mytibble0 <- tibble(A = c(1,2)) %>%
    mutate(period = 1)
mytibble <- mytibble0

for (i in 2:20) {
  temp <- mytibble0 %>%
    mutate(period = i)
  mytibble <- mytibble %>%
    add_row(temp)
}
```

Cheers
Renger

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tidyr::complete`:

```r
complete(mytibble0, A, period = 1:20)

identical(mytibble, arrange(complete(mytibble0, A, period = 1:20), period))
#[1] TRUE
```

Or, from scratch, you could use `expand.grid` or `tidyr::expand_grid`:

```r
expand.grid(A = 1:2, period = 1:20)
tidyr::expand_grid(A = 1:2, period = 1:20)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the `map_dfr()` function from the `purrr` package from `tidyverse`. This function applies a function to each element of a list and then row binds the results together into a single dataframe.

Here are some simple codes to use the function:

```
library(tidyverse) 

mytibble0 <- tibble(A = c(1,2))

mytibble <- map_dfr(1:20, ~mytibble0 %>%
                      mutate(period = .x))
```

In this code, `~mytibble0 %>% mutate(period = .x)` is a shorthand function that takes `.x` (each element from `1:20` in turn) and creates a new version of `mytibble0` with the `period` variable set to `.x`. `map_dfr()` then row binds all these individual dataframes together into a single dataframe. The result is the same as your original code, but you do not need an explicit loop or temporary variables.